# Can I declare a task without a Task block in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

So I found that annoyingly, with custom task methods, I need to always return a new Task, like in Foo0() below. But interestingly in Xamarin, you can drop the return new Task block if you put an async keyword.

Are Foo0 and Foo1 equivalent?

Is this a glitch of Xamarin implementation, or does this work in VS2012 as well?

But Foo1 gives a compiler warning, and I can't just remove the async keyword, or it will stop compiling even though the body of the code remains the same.  (I find the extra new Task block in Foo0 redundant, it should be obvious from the method declaration that I want to run a new task.)

```
// the following is explicit with returning a new task
Task<int> Foo0()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return 5;
    });
}

// the following gives warning "Async block lacks `await` operator and will run synchronously"
async Task<int> Foo1()
{
    return 5;
}

/* the following does not compile
Task<int> Foo2()
{
    return 5;
}
*/
```

Comment: On the second case, replace `return 5;` with `return await Task.FromResult(5);` Better yet, drop the `async` and the `await` on that example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this a glitch of Xamarin implementation, or does this work in VS2012 as well?

This is how `async` works in C# (both VS2012 and Xamarin).

> it should be obvious from the method declaration that I want to run a new task

Not at all. A task is nothing more than a "future"; it represents an asynchronous operation. *One possible* way to do this is by queueing work to the thread pool (such as `Task.Run`), but that is a *rare* approach in the asynchronous world.

In particular, `async` does *not* queue work to the thread pool. It is not using `Task.Run` or anything like it underneath. As the compiler warning states, it will run synchronously (on the current thread) and then return an already-completed task. This is almost certainly what you don't want, hence the warning.

So, `Foo0` and `Foo1` are completely different. `Foo0` queues work to the thread pool and returns a task representing that work. `Foo1` does the work immediately and then returns an already-completed task.

I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog if you want more information about `async` and `await`.

Comment: If Task.Run is a rare approach, what is the standard approach to run something on a background thread?

Comment: If you need to run something on a background thread, then you should use `Task.Run`. However, you usually do not need to run things on background threads (particularly on mobile platforms). First check to see if what you're doing has an asynchronous API.

Comment: Like stephan said, because Task is a promise of future work, you can also use `Task.FromResult(TResult)` if the operation already completed or if you want to retrieve a value from cache